# import a reg key using CreateProcess & regedit.exe?

Tags: createprocess, regedit

i just need a simple way to import a .reg key into the registery hive
how can i do this?
my current code looks like this:

```
#include<Windows.h>

int main()
{
    STARTUPINFO STARTINFO = { sizeof(STARTUPINFO) };
    STARTINFO.cb = sizeof(STARTINFO);
    STARTINFO.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
    STARTINFO.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION ProcessInfo;
    CreateProcess("regedit.exe /S C:\\folder\\dd.reg", NULL , NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW , NULL, NULL, &STARTINFO, &ProcessInfo);
```

from the commmand line `C:\\Windows\regedit.exe /S C:\\folder\\dd.reg`works perfectly fine, what i am doing wrong?

PS: i dont want to use `system`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the documentation for [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx).  The first parameter is just the name/path of the executable; the *second* one is the command line.

`CreateProcess(L"regedit.exe", L"/S whatever.reg", ...)`

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, im not really a programmer i just needed something quick to work.
after reading that page i was able to make it work by leaving the first parameter empty and giving the full string inside the second like as in cmd it worked perfectly after that! thanks anyway!